# Micro Optimization of HTML

Tags: html

Just for fun, I am doing some micro optimization of a site.

**Q1)**
What more can I remove/optimize on a HTML site (not inline CSS or JavaScript):

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#syntax-tag-omission
- Change doctype into `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Remove unneeded comments, space and linebreaks
- All quotes from attributes (attributes that consist from a single
  word).
- Turn necessary double quotes into single quotes.
- Remove type="text" from inputs.

**Q2)**
"A head element's start tag may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the head element is an element."
Does `<title>` count as an element?

**Q3)**
Can I go with `<link href="/css/style.css">` istead of <`link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">`? If so, will I have to set header respons in htaccess?

**Q4)**
Are there any technical drawbacks optimizing static HTML files like this? Eg. CPU cost, Google Robots, problem with javascript, moblie devices or anything else?

**Note:** I am aware of that this wont affect any noticeable page speed. This is more for fun.

Comment: You should really let a program do all this stuff (at least the whitespace/quote/end tag things).

Comment: Thanks both. ThiefMaster, I have a php script that does some of the stuff for me... Cicada, yes! It might be worth doing this on some popular sites and websites for mobile devices :)

Comment: I've read a post or two on here that explain removing whitespace within your markup is a bit of an impractical endeavor because servers with [gzip compression enabled](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) take care of this nicely for us.